# What is the most efficient way to filter a Pojo's OneToMany field retrieved in a JpaSpecification findAll?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, filtering, specification-pattern

I am using the JpaSpecification to get a list of filtered `ProfileEntity`. ProfileEntity has a `@OneToMany List<Channel> channels` field. Each of the ProfileEntitys will have 5 Channels  associated with it but I want my `findAll(Specification<ProfileEntity> spec)` to return a list of only 1 Channel (based on the included Language which is part of Channel's composite key)

Ideally I would like to leverage the existing JpaSpecification logic but I am not sure if it's possible to filter the ProfileEntity's fields in the same way that I filter ProfileEntity itself. I have been unable to find any relevant queries and my attempts to do so have been fruitless.

Either way, what's the most efficient way to make the `findAll(Specification<ProfileEntity> spec)`method returns all ProfileEntitys with only **1** associated Channel